# Relative import errors

Tags: python-3.x

I have been using the following `relative` approach to importing items:

```
from .utils import *
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working consistently, and I will often get the following error on both python3.6 and python3.7 (on both mac and ubuntu):

```
from .utils import *
```

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

The hack fix I have implemented is as follows:

```
try:
    from .utils import *
except ImportError:
    from utils import *
```

But this seems like the worst approach of all. Why does this error sometimes occur, and what would be the best approach to fix it?

Comment: What is the directory structure ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)